# Android Fragment Transaction with animation causes white flash

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, fragmenttransaction

I have two fragments.  Fragment A is initially in view.  When the user presses a button Fragment B is animated up into view using the method below.  When I pop fragment B it animates back down out of view but right as it finishes the screen flashes white.  Not sure what is causing this, only seems to happen on kit-kat not on lollipop.  The animations being used are slide up and slide down animations defined in xml.

```
@Override
public void loadFragment(BaseFragment fragment, boolean replace, boolean addToBackStack, int animIn, int animOut, int animPopIn, int animPopout) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (animIn != -1 && animOut != -1 && animPopIn != -1 && animPopout != -1) {
        transaction = transaction.setCustomAnimations(animIn, animOut, animPopIn, animOut);
    } else if (animIn != -1 && animOut != -1) {
        transaction = transaction.setCustomAnimations(animIn, animOut);
    }

    if (replace) {
        transaction = transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    } else {
        transaction = transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    }

    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction = transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }

    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I bumped with similar problem now

Answer (score 1):

For me this crash animations of bottomBarNavigation, NavigationDrawer and when I use replace fragment

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--android:animateLayoutChanges="true" //THIS LINE CRASH THE ANIMATIONS-->
```